# Reversing two elements in list, based on condition

Tags: python, list, sorting, reverse, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement a Bubble Sort algorithm.
As it says [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/), the "Bubble Sort is the simplest sorting algorithm that works by repeatedly swapping the adjacent elements if they are in the wrong order."

**Visual Representation**

> ( **5 1**  4 2 8 ) –> ( **1 5** 4 2 8 )

So far, I have been able to identify which element is greater than the other in steps of two. Once I've done that, I am having some trouble swapping those elements.

Currently, I have something like this.

**Code**

```
def bubbleSort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        if array[i] > array[i+1]:
            #My attempt of switching the two elements in a list
            array[i+1],array[i] = array[i],array[i+1]
    return array
print(bubbleSort([5,1,4,2,8]))
```

Unfortunately, due to my incorrect logic, I did not get a sorted list.

**output**

```
[1, 4, 2, 5, 8]
```

**desired output**

```
[1 ,2 ,4 ,5 ,8]
```

What am I doing wrong here, why is it not sorting correctly and what can I do to fix this problem? A detailed explanation along with the provided code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote is correct but incomplete. **You have just done the first pass.**

All you need to do is to **run all the other passes** by modifying your code to:

```py
def bubbleSort(array):
    for j in range(len(array)):
        for i in range(len(array)-1):
            if array[i] > array[i+1]:
                array[i+1],array[i] = array[i],array[i+1]
    return array
print(bubbleSort([5,1,4,2,8]))
```

You can go through this article [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) for a better understanding.

Comment: Ok, so my logic of reversing the elements where correct? But I basically did not finish my code. Beautiful. Thank you